# Resize Main Window

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt4, pyqt4

I have used the setGeometry method in order to give a size to all my widgets. I know it wasn't the best thing to do but this is the first time I use PyQt.
The problem now is that when I click on the Maximize button, all my widgets stay the same...
I have tried to use the resizeEvent, but PyQt doesn't make any difference among this event's senders : indeed this event is sent when the window in being resized with the maximize button, or with the mouse by stretching the window.

What I am looking for :
a particular signal sent when the Maximize button is pressed, so that I can catch this signal and apply my setGeometry() methods, but this time in order to fit the full screen mode.
But I don't know if such a thing exists...

If no, is there another way to do what I need?

Thank you for Reading !

Answer (score 2):

You're going about this in completely the wrong way. Qt already handles all this kind of stuff for you automatically (so long as you use the right APIs).

I suggest you do the following:

1. Read Qt's [Layout Management Overview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html).
2. Learn how to use [Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-manual.html) (especially the part about [Using Layouts](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-layouts.html)).
3. Read the [Using Qt Designer Guide](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html) in the [PyQt Documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/).

Meanwhile, here's a simple demo script:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('Layout Management Example', self)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.edit1 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.edit2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Maximize', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit1, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit2, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 2, 0, 1, 2)

    def handleButton(self):
        if self.button.text() == 'Maximize':
            self.button.setText('Restore')
            self.showMaximized()
        else:
            self.button.setText('Maximize')
            self.showNormal()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 150, 500, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```